# Inserting validation constraints using Sequel gem in PostgreSQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake, sequel

I am new to Sequel, using it for the first time.

I created a table:

```
# connect to an in-memory database
DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://ritesh:newpassword@localhost')

# create an items table
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :first_name
  String :last_name
  String :email
  String : zipcode
  String : company_name
  String : google
  String :skype
  String :phone 
  String :about
  String :linkedin_profile_url
end

end
```

I want to put a regular expression constraint on the `email` field:

```
VALID EMAIL REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

and similar validations I have to put on other columns when we use the model.

I found "[Model Validations](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/validations_rdoc.html)" for adding validation, but I am creating a table.

How do I put validation in the `create_table` method? If I have to use this table for a model, how do I convert from the table to a model, or use Model?

I am using grape only, no Rails is used. It's a simple Rake app.

Comment: Be cautious using that regex to validate the address. It can only show that the address string conforms to a small subset of the email address spec. The true spec requires a very complex pattern that is much, much, longer. And, if a string passes that test, it still doesn't mean it is valid, i.e., that there is a user at the other end. Only that can be determined by sending a message to that address and getting a response back from that person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put into your model something like:

```
class Model < Sequel::Model
  plugin :validation_helpers

  def validate
    validates_format /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i, :email
  end
end
```